# Roblox API Returns 401 Unauthorized

Tags: python, python-requests, roblox

Whenever I try to make a POST request to https://users.roblox.com/v1/description it always gave me an 401 Unauthorized

My code:

```
import requests
Security = '_'
Session  = requests.Session()
Response = requests.post('https://auth.roblox.com')
if Response.status_code == 403:
    DescriptionToken = Response.headers['x-csrf-token']
    DescriptionSession = requests.Session()
    DescriptionSession.cookies['Cookie'] = '.ROBLOSECURITY=' + Security
    DescriptionSession.headers['x-csrf-token'] = DescriptionToken
    DescriptionResponse = DescriptionSession.post('https://users.roblox.com/v1/description',{"description": "Test"})
    print(DescriptionResponse.content)
```

I tried making an csrf token header and an `.ROBLOSECURITY` cookie
I expected it to be 200 status code or something like that.
The result is saying I'm unauthorized.

Comment: Do you have any kind of documentation that this *should* work?  It looks like you're manually trying to construct a request, you've given no information on where that csrf token and security cookie comes from, or even what the basis of this request should look like.

Comment: The https://auth.roblox.com is where i get my x-csrf-token, the Security is my .ROBLOSECURITY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

cookies['Cookie'] is supposed to be cookies['.ROBLOSECURITY'], good sir.